Change in Kate behaviour after upgrade to Plasma 6
In Plasma 5.27, when I opened a text file from Dolphin, if a session is running in the current workspace, it opened the file as a new tab, and if not, it started a new session in the current workspace with the file open.
After upgrade to Plasma 6, when I open a file from Dolphin, if there are existing sessions of Kate, it switches to the workspace with the existing session and open the file there as a new tab. However, if I open the file from Konsole, as kate <filename>, it moves the window of the existing session to the current workspace and opens the file as a new tab. If launching Kate directly without opening any files, either from the applications menu or from the terminal, it starts a new session in the current workspace irrespective of any existing sessions. I find this behaviour strange. How can I go back to the old behaviour as in Plasma 5?
The applications menu entry is kate -b %U BTW.
